# SQL Combine two columns into one only using 1 set of data

Tags: sql

On the same row I have dulpicate data.
I have columns  `aCust, bCust, aPart, bPart, aSM, bSM, aSales, bSales.`

I want to combine the `Cust` together, `parts` together, and `SM` together while keeping `Sales` separate.    Some rows have data in both a and b, some a's are null and some b's are null.  How do I combine this?  If there is data in both a and b, it is always identical (except for sales).

Comment: What do mean with combine? Can you give an example?

Comment: you could do it pretty quickly with `CASE` statements

Comment: ISNULL or COALESCE are good in cases like this.

Comment: As a general rule in a relational database you should have customers in their own table, parts in their own table, and sales in their own table and link them together with foreign keys.

Comment: The problem is with the ERP system we use.  It dumps data in a table.  a's are current year data and b's are previous years data.  It dumps them on the same line where things match (cust, part, salesman, and month sold) so we can compare them but it doesnt combine the common columns.  I want to combine it with a budget table and cannot do that until the columns are combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(aCust, bCust) as Cust,
       coalesce(aPart, bPart) as Part,
       coalesce(aSM, bSM) as SM,
       aSales, bSales
from table;
```

This will choose the first non-NULL value to return for each field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. It looks weird but will do the job. You didn't specify what RDBMS you're using (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.). That's why I didn't use anything like `ISNULL`.

```
select 
    case when aCust is null then bCust else bCust end as Cust,
    case when aPart is null then bPart else bPart end as Part,
    case when aSM is null then bSM else bSM end as SM,
    aSales, bSales
from
    tbl
```

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server 2014